# Using Keyword [IN] with Case Expression in a SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-expression

I have an query like this , but it does not work , what's wrong with IN keyword with CASE EXPRESSION ?

```
Select State = case c.addressId
  when in('2552','2478','2526') then 'IN' 
  when in ('9999') then 'OUT'
  else 'UNKNOWN'
  end,
  name, time
from x;
```

I've use SQL Server 2008 and this is the error msg :

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'in'.

Comment: Oh, how great it could have been to have a comma separated list of `WHEN` expressions in simple CASE! And it doesn't even seem too hard a change to the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the syntax wrong. It should be `CASE WHEN [COLUMN] in (...)`:

```
Select 
  case when c.addressId in('2552','2478','2526') then 'IN' 
  when c.addressId in ('9999') then 'OUT'
  else 'UNKNOWN'
  end as State,
  name, time
from contact c;
```

Comment: Being pedantic -- `CASE` supports the column reference between the CASE and the WHEN, just not for IN and other forms of comparison/evaluation logic.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using a join instead.

```
SELECT ISNULL(a.[State], 'UNKNOWN') [State]
    , c.[Name]
    , c.[Time]
FROM [contact] c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT 2552 AddressId, 'IN' [State]
    UNION ALL SELECT 2478, 'IN'
    UNION ALL SELECT 2526, 'IN'
    UNION ALL SELECT 9999, 'OUT'
) [address] a ON a.AddressId = c.AddressId;
```

Comment: I can't think of a single reason why that would be better then the case/when construct. Unless you meant to pull the values from a table?

Comment: A table is a great idea. Then you can add or remove magic numbers without changing your SQL code. You can also add a descriptive field which explains each magic number.